# Control RPI Motor drive with Tkinter Lag

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
from time import sleep
import Tkinter as tk

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)

def forward(event):
    GPIO.output(13, GPIO.HIGH)
    sleep(0.2)
    GPIO.output(13, GPIO.LOW)

def back(event):
    GPIO.output(15, GPIO.HIGH)
    sleep(0.2)
    GPIO.output(15, GPIO.LOW)

def right(event):
    GPIO.cleanup()

def left(event):
    print("a")

def key_input(event):

    print 'Key:', event.char    
    key_press = event.char    
    sleep_time = 0.030

    if key_press.lower() == 'w':    
        forward(sleep_time)

    elif key_press.lower() == 's':    
        back(sleep_time)

    elif key_press.lower() == 'a':    
        left(sleep_time)

    elif key_press.lower() == 'd':    
        right(sleep_time)

root = tk.Tk()    
root.bind('<KeyPress>', key_input)    
root.mainloop()
```

When i run it on my raspbery pi b3, i have a lot of lag.. How to improve the code to run without lag, or how to change it to control the motor with my keyboard?

I just want to move my car forward, backward, right and left... I google it and i see the most used method is with tkinter...

That is unfinished code, and is just for one motor. I try to use press/release event, but don't work.. Please someone help me!!

Comment: why are you passing a time to functions that accept an event object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not be using time.sleep in a gui program, that is where your lag is coming from, you are also passing a time where you're expecting an event and then ignoring it anyway?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
import Tkinter as tk

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.bind('<KeyPress>', self.KeyDown)
        self.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.KeyUp)

    def KeyDown(self, event):
        if event.char:
            k = event.char.lower()
            if k == 'w':
                GPIO.output(13, GPIO.HIGH)
            elif k == 'a':
                GPIO.output(15, GPIO.HIGH)
            elif k == 's':
                pass
            elif k == 'd':
                pass

    def KeyUp(self, event):
        if event.char:
            k = event.char.lower()
            if k == 'w':
                GPIO.output(13, GPIO.LOW)
            elif k == 'a':
                GPIO.output(15, GPIO.LOW)
            elif k == 's':
                GPIO.cleanup()
            elif k == 'd':
                print("a")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

If you bind the press and release events separately you can turn the motor on when you press the key and off when you release it, that should eliminate most of your lag.